# Give user FULL permissions to all files without setting group to "root"

Tags: permissions, root

I am configuring my server to prevent hacker bruteforce attacks by disabling root login from ssh: by setting `PermitRootLogin no` in file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

This way I created new user (let's call it `user`) with secret name.
But when I am changing file `etc/passwd` by setting user's GID and UID to root's "0" value, it is not possible to log in (due sshd_config).

But how can I make `user` root-like but keep safe ssh logining?

Comment: What is your system version? (`lsb_release -a`)?

Comment: you log in and use `sudo program` or `sudo -i` or you log in and use `su user`

Comment: @Nmath no. This is not the case. I don't want to write SUDO at all.

Comment: @vanadium 
Operating System: CentOS Linux 8 || 
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:8  || 
Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64  || 
Architecture: x86-64.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux is it possible to not use sudo everywhere? I cannot even use sudo in WinSCP

Comment: CentOS is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). We only support official Ubuntu. CentOS has little in common with Ubuntu. [CentOS 8 is also an EOL](https://www.centos.org/centos-linux-eol/) system and is not considered safe to use. It's a bit strange to ask a question about improving security while using an EOL OS...  You can ask about CentOS on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com). That being said, I don't understand why you can't use sudo. You're absolutely right to disable root login, but you will need to give another user admin privileges.That's the purpose of sudoers